# why the converter is not running?

Tags: c#, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection, imultivalueconverter

I am using the MVVM pattern and in my view I have this `dataGrid`:

```
<Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myMultiValueConverter}">
            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                <Binding />
                <Binding ElementName="ThisControl" Path="DataContext.MyObservableCollectionInViewModel"/>
                <Binding ElementName="thisControl" Path="DataContext.ControlType"/>
                <Binding ElementName="ThisControl" Path="DataContext.ExternalItems"/>
                <Binding Path="Componentes.OneProperty"/>
            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

And my view model has this code:

```
private void myMethod()
{
    MyObservableCollectionInViewModel.Clear();
    MyObservableCollectionViewModel.Add(new myType());
}
```

When I execute the method `MyMethod()`, if a I am not wrong, the multi value converter would be run, because the `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` when I add or remove items, but in this case does not work.

However I have another `ObservableCollection` for the `DataSource` of my `dataGrid` and it works as it's expected, refresh the `dataGrid` when I add or remove items from the `ObservableCollection`.

However, if in `myMethod` I do this:

```
private myMethod()
{
    myObservableCollectionInMyViewModel.Clear();
    myObservableCollectionInMyViewModel.Add(new MyType());
    myObservableCollectionInMyViewModel = new ObservableCollection(myObservableCollectionInMyViewModel);
}
```

It works, so the view is notified when I create a new `ObservableCollection`, not when I add or remove items from the actual `ObservableCollecion`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the **correct** behavior.

The reason the `ObservableCollection` Add/Remove works for `ItemsControl`, `ListBox`, `DataGrid` etc, is that they are explictly taking care of the behavior you are describing, that is not WPF specific, eg: it doesn't have to do with the actual binding of `ItemsSource`.

What happens under the cover is, all these controls(`ListBox`, etc..) are inheriting from `ItemsControl` which ultimately wraps `ItemsSource` into `CollectionView`, which will take advantange of `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, if possible. That's how it knows / keeps up.

The "work-around" I've used successfully:

A) Just use property changed or do the swap as you've done (this might, or might not work - I don't exactly remember, but WPF might have explicit check if the actual value has been changed, in this case: it hasn't):

```
 myObservableCollectionInMyViewModel.Clear();
 myObservableCollectionInMyViewModel.Add(new MyType());
 RaisePropertyChanged(() => myObservableCollectionInMyViewModel);
```

B)

```
myObservableCollectionInMyViewModel = 
   new ObservableCollection(new List<MyType>{
      new MyType()});
```

C) Bind against .Count, as `ObservableCollection` will notify when that changes.

```
     <Binding ElementName="ThisControl" 
Path="DataContext.MyObservableCollectionInViewModel.Count"/
```

D) Create a new converter which will be able to listen all the events(INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyCollectionChanged) events, which then will trigger multi converter updates.

```
<Binding ElementName="ThisControl" 
   Converter="{StaticResource observableConverter}"
   Path="DataContext.MyObservableCollectionInViewModel"/>
```